# numbers pages too near to titlepage

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

in my document the number of page is located at top-right and is too near to the title of the page.how can I put the number of the page at the bottom?I'm using book class with oneside option

here an example

[image]

this is a small example where you can see the number page and the a part of title too near.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{setspace} %setta l'interlinea a 1,5 \onehalfspacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{layaureo}
\usepackage{graphicx} %include immagini
\usepackage{caption}  %didascalie
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}        % matematica

\begin{document}

\input{Capitoli/capitolo_1} \input{Capitoli/capitolo_2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a Minimum Working Example (MWE) of the code that generates the undesirable output you're trying to fix, and not the output itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your MWE. First of all it is not working and is not showing the error. Here is a MWE slightly modifying your MWE to make it compile and indicating that either you have included further packages that cause the problem or that the problem is caused by one of the files you are inputting.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} %setta l'interlinea a 1,5 \onehalfspacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{layaureo}
\usepackage{graphicx} %include immagini
\usepackage{caption}  %didascalie
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,lipsum}        % matematica
\title{TEST}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{GIE}
\section{test}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```